# QoS between multiple VLANs

Tags: vlan, ethernet, qos

I am currently using PFsense as my firewall and was happy until I introduced VLAN in my network. I need to be able to apply QoS over multiple VLANs:

I have a 10/2 mbit line and want following scenario:

- VLAN1: guaranteed 5/1 mbit
- VLAN2: guaranteed 3/0.5 mbit
- VLAN3: guaranteed 2/0.5 mbit

What I would like is that VLAN3 should be able to use the full line, if VLAN1 and VLAN2 is not in use or just swiftly used.

How can I provide these services?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are really after is bandwidth shaping. You may wish to read the [PFsense documentation](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Shaping_Guide) on configuring this.

Answer (score 0):

VLAN tagging of ethernet frames means that, in theory, you should be able to set up QOS rules that trigger when a particular VLAN tag is matched.

I'm not sure on specifics of your firewall PFsense, but I know it can be done with other solutions. Netscope will do it (Disclaimer, I work for them), you can set rules based on VLAN header tags.

As for free/opensource solutions, it looks like 'tc' will allow you to shape based on VLAN tags. If PFsense uses 'tc' then you're in luck.